# iOS Controller Pattern - same instance through 3 viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, design-patterns, instance, viewcontroller, tabbed

i want to use the same instance of a model class e.g.
MyClass myclass - in 3 tabs (3 view controllers).

Should i alloc this instance in a rootcontroller ?
Or is a simple way to delegate this instance throw 3 tab viewcontroller ?

Thanks

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check how to use [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

More info specific for Apple could be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html).

If you have some specific questions please post some code and I'm sure me or somebody else from the community will help you.

Comment: Thx for help. I solved it with sharedInstance - method (singleton).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Tab Bar View Controller is the app's initial view controller, you're probably best off with instantiating the Model Object in your App Delegate and then passing it off to each view controller managed by the Tab Bar View Controller.